# boto3 : AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'create_instances'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
client = boto3.client('ec2', 
        aws_access_key_id=key,
        aws_secret_access_key=secret,
        region_name='ap-southeast-1')


    response = client.create_instances(
        DryRun=True,
        ImageId=ami1,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        KeyName='my-key',
        SecurityGroupIds=[sg1, sg2],
        InstanceType='m3.medium',
        Placement={
            'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-southeast-1a'
        },
        SubnetId=sb1,
        NetworkInterfaces=[
            {
                'NetworkInterfaceId': vpc1,
                'SubnetId': sb1,
                'Description': 'Description'
            }
        ]
    )
    print response
```

getting error while making api call to create instance, I have verified other operation like describe_images is working fine so keys are proper.

am I missing something ?

Comment: shouldn't line 1 be `boto3.resource('ec2'...` instead of `boto3.client('ec2'...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using run_instances 
 https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances

Answer (score 14):

`EC2.Client` does not provide `create_instances`, as the error message indicates.

Instead, it is `EC2.ServiceResource` that provides it, according to [the boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance)

You need to update the first instruction:

```
client = boto3.resource('ec2', 
    aws_access_key_id=key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret,
    region_name='ap-southeast-1')
```

Comment: Hmm I am getting `AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'release_address'`. I am creating the object with `ec2 = session.resource('ec2')`.